# trying to find application settings file used by configurationmanager in google data api sample C# client

Tags: c#, google-api

Given this set of code:

```
unitTestConfiguration = (IDictionary) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unitTestSection");
```

where can you determine which project this file should exist in.

I am trying to run a bunch of unit tests but they are failing because it can't find any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a web application, this reads from the web.config file.

For an executable, this reads from *exename*.exe.config for the entry point assembly (the one that contains the `Main` method). This is an important distinction that the config file it reads from is the entry point assembly, not the assembly that contains the particular line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for the application configuration file. These reside in your project under the name `App.config` (or `Web.config` for `ASP.NET`) and are compiled into `YourApplicationName.exe.config`.

Here is an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx) on adding an `App.config` file to your project.

Here is an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) on the `Configuration` class.